# Metabox textarea showing whitescreen

Tags: custom-post-types

The problem is when i add textarea i get white screen without data
Below is my Code Which i got from Stack exchange.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'dynamic_add_custom_box' );

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'dynamic_save_postdata' );

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function dynamic_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box(
        'dynamic_sectionid',
        __( 'Client Information', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'dynamic_inner_custom_box',
        'page');
}

/* Prints the box content */
function dynamic_inner_custom_box() {
    global $post;
    // Use nonce for verification
    wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ), 'dynamicMeta_noncename' );
    ?>
    <div id="meta_inner">
    <?php

    //get the saved meta as an arry
    $ourwork = get_post_meta($post->ID,'ourwork',true);

    $c = 0;
    if ( is_array( $ourwork ) ) {
        foreach( $ourwork as  $track ) {
            if ( isset( $track['thumb'] ) || isset( $track['client-img1'] ) || isset( $track['client-img2'] ) || isset( $track['client-img3'] ) || isset( $track['client-img4'] ) || isset( $track['client-desc'] ) ) {
                printf( '<p>Thumb Image :&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="ourwork[%1$s][thumb]" value="%2$s" size="50" /><br/>Client Image 1 : <input type="text" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-img1]" value="%3$s" size="50" /><br/>
                Client Image 2 : <input type="text" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-img2]" value="%4$s" size="50"/><br/> 
                Client Image 3 : <input type="text" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-img3]" value="%5$s" size="50" /><br/> 
                Client Image 4 : <input type="text" name="ourwork[%1$s][client-img4]" value="%6$s" size="50" /><br/>
                Client Desc :<br/><textarea name="ourwork[%1$s][client-desc]" value=""></textarea><br/>
                <span class="remove">%8$s</span></p>', $c, $track['thumb'], $track['client-img1'], $track['client-img2'] , $track['client-img3'] , $track['client-img4'], $track['client-desc'],  __( '<span class="button">Remove</span>' ) );
                $c = $c +1;
            }
        }
    }

    ?>
<span id="here"></span>
<span class="add"><?php _e('<span class="button">Add+</span>'); ?></span>
<script>
    var $ =jQuery.noConflict();
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var count = <?php echo $c; ?>;
        $(".add").click(function() {
            count = count + 1;

            $('#here').append('<p>Thumb Image :&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="ourwork['+count+'][thumb]" value="" size="50"/><br/>client Image 1 : <input type="text" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-img1]" value="" size="50"/><br/>client Image 2 : <input type="text" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-img2]" value="" size="50"/><br/>client Image 3 : <input type="text" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-img3]" value="" size="50"/><br/>client Image 4 : <input type="text" name="ourwork['+count+'][client-img4]" value="" size="50"/><br/>client Desc:<br/><textarea  name="ourwork['+count+'][client-desc]" value=""></textarea><br/><span class="remove"><span class="button">Remove</span></span></p>' );
            return false;
        });
        $(".remove").live('click', function() {
            $(this).parent().remove();
        });
    });
    </script>
</div><?php

}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function dynamic_save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
    // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
        return $post_id;

    // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
    // because save_post can be triggered at other times
    if ( !isset( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'] ) )
        return;

    if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['dynamicMeta_noncename'], plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return;

    // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

    $ourwork = $_POST['ourwork'];

    update_post_meta($post_id,'ourwork',$ourwork);
}
```

Comment: [Turn on debugging](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and add any debugging output to your question.  That will help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I bet it's much simpler than it seems...

Replace

```
<textarea name="ourwork[%1$s][client-desc]" value=""></textarea>
```

with:

```
<textarea name="ourwork[%1$s][client-desc]">%7$s</textarea>
```

Don't forget to replace string in jQuery code, too.

2 Problems:

1. You forgot `%7$s`
2. Textarea don't use `value=""` but put value between `<textarea>` and `</textarea>` (if you use value="" it will be saved but not showed)

Comment: Thx a lot man. It works. I m new to programming So can i ask one more question what is the purpose of using this %7$s

Comment: The purpose of %7$s is the same of the other you use: %1$s, %2$s, and so on. See [PHP sprintf docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). You can accept the answer, if it works...